# Is it possible to create keybinds for Windows 11 desktops

Tags: windows-11, virtual-desktop

I am moving now from Kubuntu\Plasma to Windows 11 and the way windows does Virtual Desktops is buggering me.

I normally use 6 Virtual Desktops, arranged in 2 rows x 3 columns. For easy of easy, I like assigning a keybind to go directly to one of them (i.e. WINKEY + F1 goes to desk 1, WINKEY + F1 to desk 2 , etc. I couldn'tfind how to do either, so I would like to know how and if I could:

1. Re-arrange my Virtual Desktops in 2 rows;
2. Add a Keybind to go directly into one of them;
3. Flash the name of the Desktop I'm in when I change to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those things are unfortunately not available built-in with Windows Virtual Desktops.

You might be able to got them using 3rd party tools, but it may or may not be good enough for you. Here are some:

- [**Windows Virtual Desktop Helper**](https://github.com/dankrusi/WindowsVirtualDesktopHelper) will ***Show desktop name when switching desktops***
- [**VirtualSpace**](https://github.com/newlooper/VirtualSpace) has the options of having the desktops in rows and also switch to specific desktop with keyboard shortcut (*but given that it completely overtakes the virtual desktops it might not work with the above one to show desktop name when switching*)
- For keyboard shortcuts to switch to specific desktop there are a bunch of projeects (exampels: [**AHK-Virtual Desktop Library**](https://github.com/adrian88888888/AHK-Virtual-Desktop-Library), [**VD.ahk: Virtual Desktop**](https://github.com/FuPeiJiang/VD.ahk), [**windows-desktop-switcher**](https://github.com/pmb6tz/windows-desktop-switcher) and many more, each with their own complexities and details) that use AutoHotkey scripts to accomplish that (*but it's far from the best experience, given that the way it works is that it goes to the leftmost desktop first and then toggles until the number you chose)*

Answer (score 1):

Rearranging the desktops display is not possible under Windows.

Adding the shortcuts <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>F?</kbd> to switch virtual
desktops requires using a third-party product.
I use below the free and open-source
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following script will map those keys and switch desktops:

```
#Persistent
#NoEnv         ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SetBatchLines -1
SendMode Input ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

main(), return

RunHotkey:
    switchToDesktop(StrReplace(A_ThisHotkey, "#F", , , 1) - 1)
return

switchToDesktop(idx)
{
    global ppDesktopManager, IID_IVirtualDesktop

    DllCall(vtable(ppDesktopManager, 7), "Ptr", ppDesktopManager, "Ptr*", pDesktops)
    if (pDesktops) {
        DllCall(vtable(pDesktops, 4), "Ptr", pDesktops, "UInt", idx, "Ptr", &IID_IVirtualDesktop, "Ptr*", VirtualDesktop)
        if (VirtualDesktop) {
            DllCall(vtable(ppDesktopManager, 9), "Ptr", ppDesktopManager, "Ptr", VirtualDesktop)
            ObjRelease(VirtualDesktop) ; I assume these should be freed
        }
        ObjRelease(pDesktops)
    }
}

main()
{
    OnExit, cleanup

    OnMessage(DllCall("RegisterWindowMessage", Str, "TaskbarCreated"), "WM_TASKBARCREATED")

    static ImmersiveShell := ComObjCreate("{C2F03A33-21F5-47FA-B4BB-156362A2F239}", "{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}")
    global IID_IVirtualDesktop, ppDesktopManager
    
    try ppDesktopManager := ComObjQuery(ImmersiveShell, "{C5E0CDCA-7B6E-41B2-9FC4-D93975CC467B}", "{f31574d6-b682-4cdc-bd56-1827860abec6}")
    if (!ppDesktopManager)
        ppDesktopManager := ComObjQuery(ImmersiveShell, "{C5E0CDCA-7B6E-41B2-9FC4-D93975CC467B}", "{AF8DA486-95BB-4460-B3B7-6E7A6B2962B5}")

    GUID(IID_IVirtualDesktop, "{FF72FFDD-BE7E-43FC-9C03-AD81681E88E4}")
    ObjRelease(ImmersiveShell)

    Loop 9 {
        Hotkey, #F%A_Index%, RunHotkey
    }
    return

cleanup:
    if (ppDesktopManager)
        ObjRelease(ppDesktopManager)
    ExitApp
}

WM_TASKBARCREATED()
{
    Reload
}

vtable(ptr, n) {
    ; NumGet(ptr+0) returns the address of the object's virtual function
    ; table (vtable for short). The remainder of the expression retrieves
    ; the address of the nth function's address from the vtable.
    return NumGet(NumGet(ptr+0), n*A_PtrSize)
}

GUID(ByRef GUID, sGUID) ; Converts a string to a binary GUID
{
    VarSetCapacity(GUID, 16, 0)
    DllCall("ole32\CLSIDFromString", "Str", sGUID, "Ptr", &GUID)
}
```

This script is an adaptation from the post
[[Windows 10] Switch to different virtual desktop on Win+{1,9}](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=14881)

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)